# Where can the detailed requirements for EU Low Voltage Directive compliance be found?

Tags: safety, mains, legal

I'm designing an appliance that probably has to comply with the European Low Voltage Directive.

I've been searching for a guide on how to design a product complying with this directive, but I haven't found any.

I've found this document: http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=OJ:JOL_2014_096_R_0357_01&from=EN , but it is very general in its stipulations and doesn't contain any technical details.

Searching the internet I've found blogs etc where people talk about how to crimp ground leads to comply with safety requirements, so I believe there actually are detailed technical recommendations somewhere.

But where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several standards that show compliance with LVD. Different types of equipment have different standards. For IT equipment like Modems, Routeres etc. use IEC 60950.

Answer (score 0):

The low voltage directive is, as its name suggests, a directive. It gives qualitative guidance as to what needs to be assessed to provide CE marking. Note that it is not the only directive, there is EMC and a good dozen of others which each have a scope. It is down to the manufacturer to identify, based on the directives scopes, which directives apply.

How can one prove that a piece of equipment complies to the appropriate directives, since each of their items is qualitatively defined? By the use of standards. Standards provide actual requirements for tests or reviews to be carried out on the equipment to certify. There is a number of standards out there*, but only those which are said "harmonised" and [listed here](http://ec.europa.eu/growth/single-market/european-standards/harmonised-standards/low-voltage/index_en.htm) for the low voltage directive, are authorised to assess compliance to the directives. Once again, these standards have even more specific scopes, and it is down to the manufacturer to select which one(s) to use. Sometimes, the customer will ask for a specific standard to be used.

*: Note that just about anyone could start a standard. However, it still needs to be recognised and accepted by the community (BluRay was launched by Sony for example), and in this context, *harmonised* by the european commission.